# How to select an element with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get the href. Its a next page button. I select element by `class_name = next`. This is my code:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('next').click()
```

An error comes up saying `Element is not clickable at point (801, 553)`
I think this is happening because the selected element is the `<li>` tag, and it has no `on_click()` method.

How can I get the onclick of `<a>` tag? It has no id or class.

This is the HTML:

```
<li id="next_pag_1" class="next">
  <a href="http://www.infoempleo.com/ofertas-internacionales/pagina_2/"
     onclick="paginarDatos($(this).parent('#pagination li').attr('id')); return false;">
<span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</li>`
```

I am trying to scrape this page: http://www.infoempleo.com/ofertas-internacionales/
And want to click on the next page using selenium.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By. XPATH, '//li[@id="next_pag_1"]/a')))
element.click()
```

Comment: Still getting 'Element is not clickable'. I think its because <li> tag has no onclick.

Comment: No. If to use my code you're not clicking on `li` element, but on `a`... Modal window could cause this issue, so you can try to use `explicit wait`

Comment: still getting the error. Does this have anything to do with Chrome? Is there any way to get the anchor tag and click it?

Answer (score 0):

Its Chrome browser that is causing the problem. To be fair to the user Chrome clicks the element right in the center. Some elements are not clickable in the center. So, this is what I did:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('next')
action = ActionChains(browser)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 30, 20)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

I move to the element with offset `(elem, 30, 20)`. The element is 36x36 so 30x20 is not in the middle of the element. Then using ActionChains perform the click and it works.